# Java console input doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, string, input, console

So I wrote a programm that prints information about a book if you type in the title and it works perfectly fine if you type in the title directly as a string like that:

```
bs.getBook("book");
```

But I want it to read the title from a console input like that:

```
String inputResult = System.console().readLine();
bs.getBook(inputResult);
```

But it just doesn't work for some reason. If I just try to print the input, it prints the string that I typed in so it should actually work with getBook too but it doesn't. Did I miss something?

That's the getBook method:

```
public void getBook(String title) {
        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            if (books[i].title == title) {
                System.out.println(books[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("0");
            }
        }
    }
```

So here is an example:
if I'm typing in the book title like this:

```
bs.getBook("book");
```

it prints out the information in the console as it should do like that:

```
Book(book, 8494030, 22.1)
```

but if I try to type in the title in the command line using:

```
String inputResult = System.console().readLine();
bs.getBook(inputResult);
```

it doesn't work. If I try to print what I typed in though like that:

```
System.out.println(inputResult);
```

It prints what I typed in so why doesn't it work properly in the getBook method?

Comment: Probably yes, you missed something.  But we can't be sure without a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using eclipse or any other IDE?

Comment: @KiraKumar I am not sure, I guess not.

Comment: You are comparing String with `==` instead of `equals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't think your scanner/reader is the problem here.
In your getBook method try to compare the title with equals

```
if (books[i].title.equals(title)) {
```

I assume your `.title` method returns a String with the title of the book it would be easier to understand if you would call it `getTitle`

---

And you can try to use a buffered reader

```
    InputStream is = System.in;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    System.out.println("Enter Book Title: ");
    String input = "";

    try {
        input = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Your Input: " + input);

        is.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading input");
    }
```

Comment: Finally, thank you. It worked. And no, it doesn't return the title, it returns the information about the book (title, ISBN, price). Why did it work with `==` instead of `.equals` when I typed in the title directly as a string, though?

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference between == and equals myself but as far as I know equals compares the strings logical. == compares the reference of the variable

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the value using Scanner from command line

```
System.out.println("Enter your book name: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String bookName= scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Your book name is " + bookName);
```